# Converting DMS to DD and projecting to NAD83 StatePlane PA South, point is in Ohio

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, convert

I'm having issues plotting a point that I converted from DMS to DD on a map projected in State Plane PA South

I'm given a point...

> 77° 30’ 10.3” W, 40° 8’ 12.0” N

And need to convert it to decimal degrees for ArcGIS so...

> 77.502861,40.136667

Yet when I add this to my map and add a basemap, the point is thrown off to the west in the wrong direction...

My point has the correct projection system...

> NAD_1983_StatePlane_Pennsylvania_South_FIPS_3702

Looking in my Layers -> Properties -> Coordinate System I have the same projection...

> NAD_1983_StatePlane_Pennsylvania_South_FIPS_3702

Yet the point is somewhere off in Ohio not Pennsylvania.

[image]

Could someone help me in where I'm going wrong in my process?

I don't know which part is incorrect my conversion or how I'm projecting the data on the map.

Answer (score 3):

> 77.502861,40.136667

Should be

-77.502861,40.136667

As West is negative not positive.

Then when create a feature class from XY Table, use WGS 1984 Geographic projection and then use the Project tool to the desired projection.

From the help I got on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gis/comments/81jkj4/help_with_projectionsconversions_converting_dms/dv3k08r/).

Comment: I think you also need to switch the latitude and longitude. Negative first implies Southern Hemisphere.